# Check the date for how much older?

Tags: php

I want to check if given date is older than 30days i have to print "OUTOFDATE" else i have to print "INPROCESS"

I have tried something like this.

```
if(strtotime('2014-05-14')>strtotime('+1 Months')){
   echo "OUTOFDATE";
} else {
    echo "INPROCESS";
}
```

Help me.

Comment: You are trying to see if 2014-05-14 is more than todays date plus one month so 2014-06-14. So no 2014-05-14 is not more than 2014-06-14

Comment: @merlin2011: the syntax is right. see the [doc](http://in1.php.net/strtotime#example-2407)

Comment: So what should i do? please help.

Comment: +1 Month...no s since it's not plural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime()` is good for this as `DateTime()` objects are comparable and recommended by PHP for all date math:

```
$date1       = new DateTime('2014-05-01');
$oneMonthAgo = new DateTime('-1 month');
if ($date1 > $oneMonthAgo) {
    echo "OUTOFDATE";
} else {
    echo "INPROCESS";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
echo $start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2014-04-20'));
echo $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
if($start > $end) {
  echo "OUTOFDATE";
} 
else {
  echo "INPROCESS";
}
```

Comment: Why not compare `$start` and `$end` strings directly?

Comment: Still - why to use `strtotime`?

Comment: This is wrong. It says "if 2014-04-03 is greater than 2014-04-03 + 30 days" ... it will NEVER return true because `$start` is always less than `$start + 30 days`

Comment: Sorry, but it is still incorrect. The error is the declaration of `$start` and `$end`. You are comparing a date with itself +/- 30 days, so the conditional will never change in relation to `$start`. `$end` will always be the same distance from `$start`.

Comment: Yes that logic looks better ... Although I still don't think it solves the OPs problem. Either way, I removed my downvote because you fixed the error I was referring to :)

Comment: that sure will help OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work fine for you.

```
if(strtotime('2014-05-14')>=strtotime('+1 Months')){
   echo "OUTOFDATE";
} else {
    echo "INPROCESS";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current conditional:

```
if(strtotime('2014-05-14')>strtotime('+1 Months'))
```

says: if `2014-05-14` is **AFTER** `>` 1 month **from now**.

What you want is to check if `2014-05-14` is **BEFORE** `<` 1 month **ago**:

```
$date = '2014-05-14';

if (strtotime($date) < strtotime('30 days ago'))
   echo "OUTOFDATE";
else
    echo "INPROCESS";
```

This says: if `$date` is **OLDER** than `30 days ago`, it is "OUTOFDATE"